# Converting a generic type list to string variable

Tags: java, rest

I have generic type list. I want to check whether new data is inserted or not. so i create a count method which return the size of the list. Finally i shall compare this size with another size, to to determine new data is inserted or not. But problem is , i cannot cast this generic type list to String type.

Comment: i can't see your generic type list

Comment: Why do you want to convert your list to a string? If all you want to do is check whether the size has changed then you can leave it as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a count of the elements inside your ListMedicine instance `List`, probably your `count()` method should be doing the following (**based on how you implemented ListMedicine**)

```
public int count(){   
   WebResource wr = webResource;
   ListMedicine a = wr.path("entity.medicine/count").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(ListMedicine.class);
   return a.getListMedicines().size();
}
```

Comment: I shall compare this public int count() method with another count method to get a boolean result table new data is inserted or not.

Comment: I don't know how all of your app. works, but I think it's a yes

Comment: still don't get why you asked how to convert your listMedicine to string type

Comment: @Zeromus I thought the same before writing this answer. I'm just guessing now

Comment: @Zeromus I have a List<Medicine> class.

Comment: I am making a desktop app which will automatically load data of a remote server. I want to notify in system tray when new data is inserted, deleted or updated.

Comment: Lets say you call count() at 1.00pm, you store the integer value, then at 1.01pm you call count() another time. Just compare the stored value with the value returned by the last call.

Comment: yes if you only want to know if there is a new value then there's no need to check anything beside size

Comment: @Zeromus please check the edited question again. I created a thread to call loadData() method after 3 sec. can u help me to check the size of the database after 3 secs. I really need this.

Comment: Your solution is not a good one. You should listen for the add() method of the List. So each time you update the list you also update the systray.

Comment: @LppEdd would u plz explain which add() method? I have only at tray.add(trayIcon) to show system noticication.

Comment: it's the List interface method to add elements (Medicine elements)